# Tag JIRA item descriptions and build Documentation

Tags: jira

Is there a way to Tag portions of the Description field in JIRA items and then build a Documentation file from it? Or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom field to store the text you want to appear in a report of some kind